# Separate text in input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have simply input in html, for example:

```
<input class="check" type="text" />
```

I would like enter to this input text with separated by **#**. For example:

```
aaa# bbb# ccc# ddd
```

But how can I check and replace with jQuery that before # wasn't space and after # was space?

For example:

```
 aaa # bbb#ccc#ddd# eee
```

should replace to:

```
 aaa# bbb# ccc# ddd# eee
```

etc.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/53bac/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, then you could use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
text.replace(/\s*#\s*/g, '# ')
```

If you want to do this for all your inputs with the class `check`, you could do something like this:

```
$('#replace').click(function(){
    $('.check').each(function() {
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\s*#\s*/g, '# '));
    });
});
```

[(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/53bac/3/)

Comment: but how can i replace this in input? I dont want alert

Answer (score 1):

Here is a (non-regex) solution. It splits the string, trims it and adds `'# '` in between each item.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4uEPj/1/)

```
$('#replace').click(function(){
    $.each($('.check'), cleanup);
});

function cleanup() {
    var result = '';
    var items = $(this).val().split('#');
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        result += (i == 0 ? '' : '# ');
        result += $.trim(items[i]);
    }
    $(this).val(result);
}
```

Comment: why this return me result in alert? i would like directly replace this in all input